# How am I breaking react hooks rules?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, react-query

I have a problem with calling this single firestore doc when using router.query to extract URL params.

I have been using this same method with success to fetch collections from firestore.

The only difference is that i didnt need next router to get the url params with that piece of code, it just works.

Here is my page...

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import fetchArtist from "../../hooks/getArtists";
import Head from "next/head";
import ArtistHeader from "../../components/ArtistHeader";
import UploadButton from "../../components/UploadButton";
import styles from "../../styles/artistPage.module.css";

export default function Artist() {
  // Get the session
  const { status } = useSession();
  const router = useRouter();

  //checks to see if the user is logged in and redirects them to the login page if they are not
  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === "unauthenticated") {
      router.push("/auth/signin");
    }
  }, [status, router]);

  //fetches the artist data from the database
  const { data, status: artistStatus } = useQuery(["artist"], fetchArtist, {
    staleTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
  });

  //sets the artist data to the state
  const [artist, setArtist] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (artistStatus === "success") {
      setArtist(data);
    }
  }, [artistStatus]);

  return (
    <section className={styles.wrapper}>
      {/* <Head>
        <title>{artist.screenName}</title>
      </Head>
      <div className={styles.artistPage}>
        <ArtistHeader artist={artist} />
        <div className={styles.songContainer}>
          <UploadButton />
        </div>
      </div> */}
    </section>
  );
}
```

Here is my data fetch...

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { getDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../pages/api/auth/firebase/config";

export default async function fetchArtist() {
  const router = useRouter();
  if (router.isReady && router.query.artistId) {
    const artistId = router.query.artistId;
    console.log("artistId is: ", artistId);
    const artistRef = doc(db, "users", artistId);
    const artistDoc = await getDoc(artistRef);
    console.log("Data is: ", artistDoc);
    return artistDoc.data();
  }
}
```

The data logs as undefined and I get the following error without the fetchArtist code firing...

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I cannot see where I am breaking hook rules and I really don't think I have mismatching versions or multiple versions.

FYI - If I call the fetchArtist() function directly it pulls back the data object requested without issue and the console.logs in the fetch work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's saying that you're breaking the rule that hooks must be called at the top level of a component. When you call it directly, it works, when you let useQuery call it, it breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `useRouter` in `fetchArtist`.  You should pull `useRouter` up to the top level of the component and create a function which uses the values so you can pass it in, like

```
 const router = useRouter();

 const fetchArtistWithRouter = () => {
   if (router.isReady && router.query.artistId) {
    const artistId = router.query.artistId;
    console.log("artistId is: ", artistId);
    const artistRef = doc(db, "users", artistId);
    const artistDoc = await getDoc(artistRef);
    console.log("Data is: ", artistDoc);
    return artistDoc.data();
  }
 }

const { data, status: artistStatus } = useQuery(["artist"], fetchArtistWithRouter , {
    staleTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
  });
```

That may not be fully correct if you need things like cancellation behavior or whatever may rerender the component, but the general idea works.